# What IDE should I use to develop hta files that automate Word and Excel?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, hta

Which version of Visual Studio Express should I use to develop an HTA application that will script Word and Excel and connect to a web service?

Should I download the web edition because hta files are like web pages, or should I download one of the others because hta files work on the local machine? Or is there another IDE I can use?

Answer (score 1):

*SharePoint Designer 2007* which is now free to use. *FrontPage 2003* if you already have it. I feel that FrontPage/SharePoint HTML editing is awesome, especially the VBA support during design-time editing. When you want to view the HTML Application, just press F12.

*Visual Web Developer Express* will also work well. Note that *Visual Studio 2008* versions use "SharePoint Designer 2007" as the HTML editor. Even though *Visual Studio* uses the same HTML editor, the editor user-interface is much better in *SharePoint Designer 2007* or *FrontPage 2003*.

To debug see the below reference.

- *Debugging VBScript and JScript in vbs, js, wsf and hta files* at http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/maikkoster/archive/2009/03/25/debugging-vbscript-and-jscript-in-vbs-js-wsf-and-hta-files.aspx
- *Microsoft Visual Studio: Editing HTA files with VS2005 - debugging* at http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/30906/, but use the Stop (VBScript) or stop; (JScript) statements instead of a message box statement.
- *HTML Applications* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471.aspx.
- *Extreme Makeover: Wrap Your Scripts Up in a GUI Interface* at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx

  > HTML Applications (HTAs) provide a way for you to wrap your scripts up in a graphical user interface, an interface replete with check boxes, radio buttons, drop-down lists and all those other Windows elements you’ve grown to love. In this article, the first of a multi-part series, we’ll introduce the basics behind creating your very own HTA.
- *HTA Helpomatic* at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=231D8143-F21B-4707-B583-AE7B9152E6D9&displaylang=en

  > Utility to help script writers create HTML Applications (HTAs).